# SharePoint 2010 List Datasheet View error when editing the data

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010, sharepoint-list, datasheet

Our `SharePoint` users have `Contribute permission` on the list but still get the following error when trying to edit data in the `datasheet view`:

[image]

I am able to edit the list but I have the Full Control. `Contribute permission` alone should allow the users to edit the list data. The list is not Read-Only as the [Content Approval](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2274841) option in the list is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this will be it, but have you checked to ensure the item doesn't have unique permissions?

Comment: I meant, the individual item that they are trying to edit within the list. On re-reading it sounds like they have trouble editing all items within the list though, rather than just one. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, they have trouble editing all items within the list.